# Encrypting an image to send a string of text

Tags: encryption, theory

for a project I am working on, I have created a (probably not entirely) new way to encrypt a string of text. The text is re-arranged at random and the instructions of the ordering of the letters is basically the key given to the person at the other end. The other person uses the ordering of the letters (the key) to run through the text file sent and get the sent text. For example I would send the private message: The cow jumped over the fox. The re-ordering would make the public message (case is not important in this example) eewuv xhompo e ot tefhrvdj. Then the person on the other end uses the order of the letters to get the letters in the right order, and get the message. This is very similar to an anagram, and for a longer document (100 words +), it should be very difficult to decrypt. Would this form of encryption work in making the message impossible or very difficult to decrypt? Any other thoughts welcome.

EDIT: A very good point on rolling my own encryption scheme, thanks Blorgbeard and agamike.

Comment: The key is the *entire* ordering? So, the key is the same length as the message? Not very practical.. And in that case, you might as well use a one-time pad.

Comment: Also, I hope this project is just for fun.. [You should never roll your own crypto](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) for any serious application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a transposition, see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_cipher#Transposition_ciphers

Generally if a key is weak the cipher/encryption is weak too.

BTW, how does it all relate to the 'image' in the title "Encrypting an image .." ?